# Import csv into database with php and with NOT EXIST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ssms

SQL agent (in SSMS) is exporting output.csv (from query). Then it moves this csv file (comma delimited) into another server, where I run php script, which is automatically importing (task scheduler) this csv file into mysql database (xampp - phpmyadmin).

```
try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
    $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
  LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";
```

I would like to add something like: if this value U_ScID exists dont import this value.

```
WHERE T3.U_CreateDate > DATEADD(hour,-12,GETDATE()-1) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT T5.U_ScID FROM [xxx].[dbo].[table] where T5.U_ScID = T0.U_ScId)
```

Do you have any idea, how should I do it?

Comment: Are you really using MySQL here? Looks more like MS SQL Server to me...

Comment: On server 1, I have SSMS, where I run SQL job. This exports csv delimited file. Then it sends into server B. In server B, there is XAMPP running phpmyadmin, which is MySQL

Comment: I know I should edit **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
      LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));** but dont know how to put WHERE clause